# Cannot deduce template arguments for basic_string

Tags: c++, templates

I have this function definition in my code:

```
template <
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> bytes2string(const Bytes& bytes)
{
     // do work ...
}
```

And when I try to call the function like this:

```
int main()
{
    Bytes bytes{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};

    std::string str = bytes2string(bytes); // error

    return 0;
}
```

I am met with the following error:

```
error: 
      no matching function for call to 'bytes2string'

note: 
  candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'CharT'
> std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> bytes2string(const Bytes& bytes)
```

I'm pretty sure it should work but alas, it doesn't. Also `Bytes` is just a `std::vector<char>` in case anyone wanted to know.

Comment: How do you expect the template parameters to be deduced?

Comment: Well `std::string` is really `std::basic_string<char>` so I would have expected the compiler to pick up on that. In this particular case `CharT` should get deduced as `char`

Comment: Without any source for `CharT` in the arguments, there's no way for it to figure out what the template parameters should be.  You're plainly expecting to assign the result to a `std::string`, so you want `CharT` to a basic char, but that doesn't factor into the parameter deduction.

Comment: in `C++` the return type doesn't participate in overload resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at your signature:

```
template <
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator> bytes2string(const Bytes& bytes);
```

There's nothing that allows `CharT` to be deduced - it needs to be explicitly supplied by the user.

---

```
std::string str = bytes2string(bytes);
```

Unfortunately C++ doesn't have [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) type inference - it is not possible to deduce template parameters of a return type in this way. Function template parameters can only be deduced via arguments passed to the function.

If you change your signature  to:

```
template <
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>, 
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> void bytes2string(std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& out, const Bytes& bytes);
```

And invoke:

```
std::string str;
bytes2string(str, bytes);
```

Your template parameters will be deduced.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GWeCClEKvI0If59C)

Comment: Damn. I was under the impression it supported such inferences. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the function is supposed to return `std::string`, then write it that way:

```
std::string bytes2string(const Bytes& bytes);
```

If it's supposed to be able to produce arbitrary instantiations of `std::basic_string` then you need to supply the appropriate template arguments. Often that's done by passing in a string of the appropriate type. That doesn't seem appropriate here, since there is no obvious use for passing in a string other than to provide template arguments.

The alternative is to name the appropriate types at the point of the call:

```
std::string str = bytes2string<char>(bytes);
```

Comment: Yep, I guessed as much but I really wanted the type deduction. Thanks